# Trigger on ApexClass Object

Tags: apex, logging

I want to try to log changes on apex classes in my org. Everytime the apex class is edited by someone i want to log the username and timestamp. Sounds easy but as i tried to write a simple trigger on the `ApexClass` object i got an error:

> Error: Compile Error: SObject type does not allow triggers: ApexClass

This is what i've tried so far without any luck:

```
trigger myTrigger on ApexClass(after update) {
}
```

Is there any workaround for this approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Triggers are not allowed on Apex classes. I think the solution here is a behavioral and process one and not a trigger. In my opinion, all code should be kept in some version control system. Changes should be committed, tested and reviewed prior to deploying to production. The advantage of a VCS is the ability to track changes and rollback as needed.

Comment: Hi mast0r, you can check this url if want to use version control - http://shivasoft.in/blog/salesforce/salesforce-git-eclipse-egit-better-and-distributed-source-control/

Answer (score 8):

You can't execute triggers on the ApexClass object. Unfortunately, there is no in-system method for tracking changes. See [Apex Code History - Ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iOwtAAE) on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).

Comment: :( I will try to vote

Answer (score 4):

Far from ideal but this can be accomplished by doing your saves with an ant script that also calls a rest endpoint that can query for the change in `ApexClass` and update some other record.

Alternatively, [Aside.io](https://www.aside.io) is a Force.com IDE that does what you are seeking, saving the information in `Aside_Code_Update__c` records.  Note: You need to enable "Org Code Search" for this to occur.